# What is the correct way to configure target_link_libraries in CMakeList when using multiple libraries? Getting Cannot specify link libraries error

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, zeromq

I am working on a project which uses the [fast-cpp-csv-parser](https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser) and [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) libraries and want to add zmq (0mq) however cannot get CMakeList to work.

The following is a working `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(sample_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(SOURCE_FILES source/main.cpp include/csv.h include/date.h)


find_package (Threads)
add_executable(sample_project ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries (sample_project ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

As per [zmq instructions](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq) the following has to be added to `CMakeLists.txt` (ZMQ and CPPZMQ is already installed).

```
find_package(cppzmq)
if(cppzmq_FOUND)
    include_directories(${cppzmq_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(sample_project ${cppzmq_LIBRARY})
endif()
```

When I add the above code to `CMakeLists.txt`, it looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(sample_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(SOURCE_FILES source/main.cpp include/csv.h include/date.h)

find_package(cppzmq)
if(cppzmq_FOUND)
    include_directories(${cppzmq_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(sample_project ${cppzmq_LIBRARY})
endif()

find_package (Threads)
add_executable(sample_project ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries (sample_project ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

And results in the following error:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake/cppzmq/cppzmqConfig.cmake:44 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindZeroMQ.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ZeroMQ", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ZeroMQ" with any
  of the following names:

    ZeroMQConfig.cmake
    zeromq-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ZeroMQ" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ZeroMQ_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ZeroMQ"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "sample_project" which is not
  built by this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/greg/CLionProjects/sample_project/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/greg/CLionProjects/sample_project/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Finished]
```

How to correctly add additional libraries using `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: The problem is that cppzmq can't find libzmq. Perhaps some of the suggestions [here](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/issues/127) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reorder your `CMakeLists.txt` so that the `target_link_libraries` is located after `add_executable`.

For instance:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(sample_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(SOURCE_FILES source/main.cpp include/csv.h include/date.h)

find_package(cppzmq)
if(cppzmq_FOUND)
    include_directories(${cppzmq_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

find_package (Threads)
add_executable(sample_project ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries (sample_project ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})

if(cppzmq_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(sample_project ${cppzmq_LIBRARY})
endif()
```

As a side remark, I would recommend using [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) instead of `include_directories`. This would also allow to pack together all `cppzmq`-related stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out with this one. How to use `target_include_directories` instead of `include_directories`? When I substitute them I get `target_include_directories called with incorrect number of arguments`. I tried adding `sample_project` to the arguments however that resulted in `Cannot specify include directories for target "sample_project" which is not built by this project.`

Comment: @Greg It would f.i. be `target_include_directories(sample_project PUBLIC ${cppzmq_INCLUDE_DIR})`. I like this command since it tells that you want these include directories only for `sample_project`, it will not contaminate other targets that may be defined later on.